# PHP PDO + PostgreSQL Connection Error: Could not find Driver

Tags: php, database, postgresql, apache, pdo

There are a few similar questions that I have read through and followed the advice but to no end, and only being fairly new to this, I figured now was a good time to stop 'trying' things in case I break anything any further.

**I'm receiving the following error when trying to connect to my database via PDO:**

`Connection error: could not find driver`

**1. I've ensured that Apache is linked to my homebrew PHP.**

```
    $ which php
    /usr/local/bin/php
```

**2. Have uncommented the following in `php.ini`**

```
extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
```

*The pdo_pgsql module shows up in php_info*

**3. My database connection is:**

```
    <?php
        class Database
        {
            public $conn;
            public function getConnection()
            {

                try {
                    $this->conn = new PDO("postgres://$user:$pass@$host:$port/$db_name");
                    print_r($this->conn);
                    $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                    $this->conn->exec("set names utf8");
                } catch (PDOException $exception) {
                    echo "Connection error: " . $exception->getMessage();
                    exit();
                }

                return $this->conn;
            }
        }
```

*I've triple checked these details and they are correct (albeit ommitted). I can connect with the same URI via IntelliJ's Database connection Wizard*

**4. I’ve edited** `/usr/local/var/postgres/postgresql.conf` **to include:**

```
#listen_addresses = '*'
```

I'm still not having any luck and am looking at some guidance in this head scratcher.

Comment: The php command is actually separate from the Apache PHP module. You are also able to specify a different php.ini for Apache as well. php -r "phpinfo();" will give you a lot of information about your install. Creating a web page with phpinfo will also allow you to see your Apache module configuration. Do not keep this web page in production or on a web accessible server. It gives out way too much info. See this webpage: https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-check-php-modules-with-phpinfo/

Comment: Hey Eric,  
Thanks for your response.  
I have checked that the module exists in phpinfo output as stated above and there is definitely an entry for `pdo_pgsql` (one column heading is PDO Driver for PostgreSQL).

Answer (score 3):

As I see you are using Linux, but tried enable .dll library which is used for Windows machines. It makes sense to comment this line.

Make sure that you have pdo_pgsql module enabled:

```
# php -m | grep pdo_pgsql
pdo_pgsql
```

Install it if it is not

```
# yum install php-pgsql
```

[Here is steps](https://varunver.wordpress.com/2016/06/03/centos-7-install-php-and-postgres/) that I did to make PHP+PostgreSQL work on my clean CentOS 7 install:

1. Install PostgreSQL (but I think you already have this installed and
           configured)

   ```
   # yum install postgresql-server postgresql-contrib
   ```
2. Updated config /var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf, changed from ident to md5

   ```
   host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
   host    all             all             ::1/128                 ident
   ```

   After

   ```
   host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
   host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
   ```

   Restart postgresql service

   ```
   # service postgresql restart
   ```
3. Install PHP and PDO connector

   ```
   # yum install php php-pgsql
   ```

Here is an example of PHP script I used to test connection:

```
<?php

//  Configure DB Parameters
$host = "localhost";
$dbname = "masterdb";
$dbuser = "automation";
$userpass = "fGmK4hvDZPB6fr6c";

$dsn = "pgsql:host=$host;port=5432;dbname=$dbname;user=$dbuser;password=$userpass";

try{
 // create a PostgreSQL database connection
 $conn = new PDO($dsn);

 // display a message if connected to the PostgreSQL successfully
 if($conn){
 echo "Connected to the $dbname database successfully!";
 echo "\n";
 }
}catch (PDOException $e){
 // report error message
 echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

And the output:

```
# php pdo_test.php
Connected to the masterdb database successfully!
```